# Greedy Regex for varying number of new line

Tags: javascript, regex

for example I have following rtf text

```
{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252
\deff0{\fonttbl{\f0\froman\fcharset0 Times New Roman;}{\f1\froman\fcharset0 HELVETICA;}{\f2\froman\fcharset0 Arial;}{\f3\froman\fcharset0 unknown;}{\f4\froman\fcharset0 HELVETICA-BOLD;}{\f5\froman\fcharset0 Helvetica;}}
{\colortbl\red0\green0\blue0;\red255\green255\blue255;\red244\green245\blue255;\red254\green182\blue230;\red0\green0\blue255;}
{\stylesheet 
{\style\s0 \ql\fi0\li0\ri0\f2\fs24\cf0 Normal;}
{\style\s3 \ql\fi0\li0\ri0\f2\fs26\b\cf0 heading 3;}
{\style\s2 \ql\fi0\li0\ri0\f2\fs28\b\i\cf0 heading 2;}
{\style\s1 \ql\fi0\li0\ri0\f2\fs32\b\cf0 heading 1;}
}
{\*\listtable
{\style\s0 \ql\fi0\li0\ri0\f2\fs24\cf0 Normal;}
{\style\s3 \ql\fi0\li0\ri0\f2\fs26\b\cf0 heading 3;}
{\style\s2 \ql\fi0\li0\ri0\f2\fs28\b\i\cf0 heading 2;}
{\style\s1 \ql\fi0\li0\ri0\f2\fs32\b\cf0 heading 1;}
}
{\*\listtable
}
{\*\listoverridetable
}
{\*\generator iText 2.1.2 (by lowagie.com)}
{\info}
```

My regex is

```
\{\\rtf1\\ansi\\ansicpg1252(?:.|[\r\n]+)*\{\\\*\\listtable
```

The problem is it doesn't look greedy. How to make it.

https://regex101.com/r/bA8iC9/2

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/bA8iC9/3?

Comment: Does it handles new line? In your test its working but for my given text it is not working. May be problem with encoding. Let me try with javascript regex for file.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: My lines are having \r\n so your suggestion not working.

Comment: JS does not support a DOTALL modifier, replace `.*?` with `[\w\W]*?`

Comment: Any particular reason you're not using an RTF parser?

Comment: Lot. I don't know how to do that properly. Just learning javascript and node js. I searched for converting it to html but not efficient for my task. Will search on it.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: yes it is duplicate. The question doesn't talk about greedyness so I thought not the same. But the answer is talking about. can be closed.